# Why SIMD only improves performance by only a little bit for RGB to Grayscale, with SIMD multiply but scalar add of vector elements?

Tags: c#, simd, sse, unsafe, parallel.for

I am learning how to use SIMD for image processing. However, I wonder why I have not seen much improvement in the performance after using SIMD.

- Image size:   3840*2160
- Image format: PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
- Function:     24bit to 8bit

1. Normal way with unsafe & Parallel.For: 48ms in average

```
static void GrayViaParallel(BitmapData org, BitmapData des)
{
    int width = org.Width;
    int height = org.Height;

    var orgp = (byte*)org.Scan0.ToPointer();
    var desp = (byte*)des.Scan0.ToPointer();

    Parallel.For(0, height, i =>
    {
        int orgSd = i * org.Stride;
        int desSd = i * des.Stride;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //                              Red                     Green                  Blue
            desp[desSd] = (byte)((orgp[orgSd + 2] * 19595 + orgp[orgSd + 1] * 38469 + orgp[orgSd] * 7472) >> 16);
            desSd++;
            orgSd += 3;
        }
    });
}
```

2. Implemented SIMD: 32ms in average

```
static void GrayViaParallelAndSIMD(byte* src, byte* dst, int count)
{
    var Coeleft = Vector128.Create(mulBlue, mulGreen, mulRed, mulBlue, mulGreen, mulRed, mulBlue, mulGreen);
    var CoeRight = Vector128.Create(mulRed, mulBlue, mulGreen, mulRed, mulBlue, mulGreen, mulRed, 0);

    int allPixels = count * 3;
    byte* srcEnd = src + allPixels; //Is it wrong?
    int stride = 15; //Proceed 15 bytes per step
    int loopCount = (int)((srcEnd - src) / stride);

    Parallel.For(0, loopCount, i =>
    {
        int curPos = (i + 1) * stride;
        if (curPos < allPixels) //If not added,  it will exceed the image data
        {
            // Load the first 16 bytes of the pixels
            var _1st16bytes = Sse2.LoadVector128(src + i * stride);

            // Get the first 8 bytes
            var low = Sse2.UnpackLow(_1st16bytes, Vector128<byte>.Zero).AsUInt16();
            //Get the next 8 bytes
            var high = Sse2.UnpackHigh(_1st16bytes, Vector128<byte>.Zero).AsUInt16();

            // Calculate the first 8 bytes
            var lowMul = Sse2.MultiplyHigh(Coeleft, low);
            // Calculate the next 8 bytes
            var highMul = Sse2.MultiplyHigh(CoeRight, high);

            //               Blue                     Green                   Red
            var px1 = lowMul.GetElement(0)  + lowMul.GetElement(1)  + lowMul.GetElement(2);
            var px2 = lowMul.GetElement(3)  + lowMul.GetElement(4)  + lowMul.GetElement(5);
            var px3 = lowMul.GetElement(6)  + lowMul.GetElement(7)  + highMul.GetElement(0);
            var px4 = highMul.GetElement(1) + highMul.GetElement(2) + highMul.GetElement(3);
            var px5 = highMul.GetElement(4) + highMul.GetElement(5) + highMul.GetElement(6);

            //15 bytes for 5 pixels 
            var i5 = i * 5;

            dst[i5    ] = (byte)px1;
            dst[i5 + 1] = (byte)px2;
            dst[i5 + 2] = (byte)px3;
            dst[i5 + 3] = (byte)px4;
            dst[i5 + 4] = (byte)px5;
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or how can I enhance it, please?
I would be very grateful for any advice.

I have experimented with different SIMD approaches, but none of them seem to work well. I am looking for a substantial boost in efficiency.

Comment: By the way:
const ushort mulBlue = (ushort)(0.114 * 0x10000);
const ushort mulGreen = (ushort)(0.587 * 0x10000);
const ushort mulRed = (ushort)(0.299 * 0x10000);

Comment: Scalar element access like `lowMul.GetElement(0)` basically defeats SIMD, the compiler probably has to store the multiply result and do scalar loads of each element.  Scalar integer multiply isn't the expensive part, although it is limited to 1/clock on current CPUs.  You need to come up with SIMD shuffles to line data up for a vertical `add`; perhaps SSSE3 `pshufb` can help to deal with the groups of 3 being an odd size.

Comment: Have you checked that the [`Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated) is `true`?

Comment: What happens when you use a normal `for`/`foreach` loop instead of the `Parallel.For` loop? In my experience parallelizing SIMD operations is too much. You might have found the limits of the internal memory bus. Also have you experimented with different [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) configurations, like `2`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: They're using `Vector128` not just `Vector`, and `Sse2.UnpackLow`.  I assume that wouldn't run at all if it wasn't on an x86-64 (or x86 with SSE2), unlike the portable `Vector` API which only provides some simple vertical operations.  I wouldn't have been surprised if the SIMD code was slower than scalar, especially if those `lowMul.GetElement(1)` accesses compile to `pextrw eax, xmm, 1` instead of store and reload.  (Intel and AMD both have 1/clock `pextrw` to a register, vs. 2 per clock loads, so if you want every element of a vector, store/reload is good for small elems.)

Comment: [How to process a 24-bit 3 channel color image with SSE2/SSE3/SSE4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376780) has some links.  Deinterleaving into vectors of red, green, and blue would set you up for `pmullw` and vertical `paddw`.  Perhaps you could use SSSE3 `pmaddubsw` if the scale factors fit in signed integers, to do 8-bit multiply and add horizontal pairs if you had pixels isolated from each other enough.  Or just with 0 as the multiplier in some elements.

Comment: @PeterCordes Appreciated. Is there a link which is SSSE3 pshufb related could be shared, please? I would like to get more information about it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have verified that Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated is “true”. However, it still takes an average of 50ms for a normal for/foreach loop. For the “MaxDegreeOfParallelism” parameter, I have tried using “Environment.ProcessorCount” which is 8, and it did reduce the average time to 20ms. Other values, such as 2 or 4, did not make much difference. Actually, I am testing it for a comparation with OpenCVSharp which only takes 3 or 6ms...

Comment: Some of the links in that Q&A (including https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1I0-SiHid1hTsv7tjLST2dYW5YF5AJVfs9l4Rg9rvz48/edit#slide=id.g1eefe20b_0_160) mention using `_mm_shuffle_epi8` (the C++ intrinsic for it).  I don't know the C# intrinsics, but the hard part figuring out what sequence of asm instructions are useful; getting a compiler to emit them from intrinsics in whatever language is a just a matter of checking the docs or a rosetta-stone guide, since you're using C# Sse2. and Ssse3. whatever which gives you access to everything.

Comment: Is OpenCV using the GPU for this?  It's probably possible to go about 10x faster than your current code with clever use of AVX2, but I wouldn't be surprised if a GPU can go even faster.  Or not, if data transfer time is too expensive; it's not *that* much work per byte.

Comment: Can you use `Vector256` what is the result of `Vector256.IsHardwareAccelerated`

Comment: Check that version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976151/126995

Comment: @PeterCordes Appreciated. That link helps a lot! And for the OpenCVSharp type convertion of Mat.CvtColor, I am not sure whether the GPU is used.  
10x faster by using AVX2... That is really interesting. May I have more information about it, please?

Comment: @Charlieface Before I changed the framework from .Net6 to .Net7, Vector256 has no "IsHardwareAccelerated" property. And the result is a "true" when I did the change.

Comment: @Soonts Thank you for sharing the link. It is exactly the first helpful lesson I learned about SIMD. :)

Comment: @Mweidy: I mostly just meant it was plausible that OpenCV was getting those speeds with well-optimized code running on a CPU.  The best possible with AVX2 might be somewhat less than 2x as fast as an optimal SSE4.1 version that avoids scalar element access.  (Unless SSE4.1 comes close to a mem B/W bottleneck, in which case  that's the limiting factor.  But reading 3840x2160 x 3 bytes in 3 ms is "only" 7.7 GiB/s, plus writing an output of 1 byte per pixel is another 2.6 GiB/s, or 5.1 if we include the RFOs if not using NT stores.  So total traffic about 12.9 GiB/s for 3ms w/ no cache hits)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your reply. I learned something new. :)